# while文内でインデントエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python

python version 2.7.10

マンデロブロ集合を描こうとして下記のプログラムを作成していたところ

```
  File "mandelplot.py", line 33
    List.append(z)
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

というエラーが出力されてしまいます。
調べてもわからず、何がまちがえているのか見当がつきません。
簡単なことを見落としているのでしょうか。

```
class Mandel(object):
    def mandelbrot(self,c, K, LOOPMAX):
        #発散まで回したループ数を返す
        List = []
        n = 0
        z = 0.0 + (0.0 * 1j)
        while(n<LOOPMAX and abs(z)<K):
            z = z**2 + c
            List.append(z)
            if(n>4):
                List.pop(0)
                eval1 = List[0] - List[4]
                eval2 = List[0] - List[3]
                if (abs(eval1)<10e-5 or abs(eval2)<10e-5):
                    break
            n += 1
        return n
```

Answer (score 4):

タブ文字とスペース文字が混在していないか、改めて確認してみてください。Pythonインタプリタ実行時に [`-t`オプションまたは`-tt`オプション](https://docs.python.jp/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t) を指定すると、この種のミスを簡単に検知できます。

また、タブ／スペースを視覚的に区別できるテキストエディタのご利用をおすすめします。

参考までに、Python標準ライブラリのコーディング規約を定める [PEP-8](http://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/) では、[スペースの利用](http://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/#id7) が推奨されています。強いこだわりが無ければ、PEP-8に従っておいたほうが良いですね。

Answer (score 0):

多分その行にタブと空白が混在しているのでしょう。

【Python】初心者がよく出すエラーメッセージ
http://blog.bakorer.com/archives/50555189.html